# Ensuring unbiased number generation within a range using RDRAND instruction

Tags: assembly, random, x86-64, nasm, rdrand

Working on a [code golf challenge](https://tio.run/##TZDPbsIwDMbvfgqLCwcyRCjqoLvssqdA1ZR/morcBjnZFNDevWvSsu0Q2f5s//IlKgTXa7o9DSr042jQaly94gqCM7HzA251CEDILmisDn9ydCnCB3mtCN9DVBxhDk3vv1DfojvTRtatWH@vEf5pVdUKuUNgy2qwqFJu3hOy3AtF8ySJXUlYHoSs4VqYbFIuSnoSBNwsCD7CHIQsXUXibDZ8bHN15lObuaa/litYJ7gMDn1RptH6ABeHAZS1uaz2cJkaHkITPvWi@GYmbeRzgXWDmTyUoAnI@4k9G1NpMcG2e2ShE7RoSeQ/vAWjiMA6k1842bnjdXx5S138hdQ7SJ4LZTqPlfEH) which requires using the [RDRAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND) hardware random number generator.

**Examples**

Set `r12` to a random number `[0,255]`

```
rdrand ax
movzx r12,al
```

Set `r8` to a random number `[0,1]`

```
rdrand r8
and r8,1
```

**Question**

I'm assuming the above examples are non-biased?

But, suppose the challenge required generating a random number in the range `[0,N]`, say `N=512`, are there any biases introduced? If so, what's the correct assembly code to generate a non-biased random number from `[0,N]`?

**Update**

Based upon the comment

> For power-of-2 ranges, just mask out the bits you want.

Perhaps this [example](https://tio.run/##tVPNjtsgEL7zFHPbrepGtqv04JyqPVSVKlVqj5EVYUMcthgsILtOXz4dIMbORkoPVX1IYAa@P4Bay/tGnj4oavvzeQPfj244OqBgqGK6B3XsG25gb3DMaXvw9Y7DNs/WRVlnflCu1zXgaj8u6hUhlrdOaAWrxloC@CEIGG4ZFLD8pt7OOuP7DRTl1JpBHB8d6aRuqARcSY0jJP5XJCBs4AtX3FDHb2QflRMShANhQShwBz7rB28gAPT6BdirNmyL29BTTgx35pRXoWuYx0TzY5g@qxZiO0wvrQyKvPyIUr6JHulmIqcDl@/WfrL3YhQOihwa4WI@bT9EkLUPYANPB97@ArEPOBcr6OBVuAO6mLSv4PEHf77E9JP2gxSqexdF0otGiAF93QNt9Av3@zLoUlwdFYqkDC72J6ctldJr3Tm9o7YVYq4Oxtfx2JCR/PUUbpL3N@Ze8sVV8uZt8sVbxVT@Z8HFXbnlfblluijYyv5ZfCrzUbjdYHRnaE/IcmuVOMKtCkSpZJjIplcXlTEWi0WeFjUnjGWL1eAyobXhopOV1HqIJMK7bKLjURvgDJfgTygwEfYkFiYzeMgfYo@3nnVOI5KxmIbj1kXx87v7DYF3NmJR8wSBSROyDKq68rLFxe9RZ53lY/75RnmAC6/4OqblFLvTcnuy/gRm4uVRVNeIn/KUTYCcBE8Y5/Mf) will work by looking at a 2^10 range then masking the bits?

```
    ; Generate a random number until it is in the range [0, 512]
    mov dword[num], 0
retry0:
    rdrand eax
    jnc retry0
    and eax, 1023 ; Limit the range to [0, 1023] to fit into 10 bits
    cmp eax, 512  ; Check if the number is within [0, 512]. (Rejection Sampling)
    ja retry0     ; If above 512, generate again

    mov [num], eax
```

Comment: For power-of-2 ranges, just mask out the bits you want.  `rdrand` should return an unbiased number if it succeeds.  For other ranges, use [Lemire's algorithm](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/06/06/nearly-divisionless-random-integer-generation-on-various-systems/).

Comment: For code-golf, if you don't have any performance requirements you could skip the AND.  And save a byte of code size (REX prefix) with `rdrand eax` since you want the high bits of RAX to be zero anyway.  Also, codegolf answers only have to work on at least one system, and Ivy Bridge couldn't exhaust its RNG so the `jnc` retry wasn't needed.  (At least with the original microcode; IDK if Intel updated CPUs as old as IvB with their changes that make rdrand *much* slower to work around possible leaks of buffer state.)

Comment: Ah, so I can omit the `jnc`, I wasn't sure because I was reading this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413839/what-are-the-exhaustion-characteristics-of-rdrand-on-ivy-bridge) and it mentioned `CF = 0   Destination register all zeros. Random value not available at time of execution. May be retried.` Thanks.

Comment: So `rdrand eax` / `cmp eax, 512` (or `cmp ax, 512` which is actually shorter: +1 byte for operand-size prefix, -2 bytes from an imm16 instead of imm32.  As a bonus it ignores the high bits, as if you'd masked with 65535 so it succeeds much more often).  If you're not just storing the result but also need it zero-extended into RAX, then `rdrand eax` / `cmp eax, 512`/`ja retry`.  I don't think we can get away with `cmp ah, 512>>8` or something, because we need to allow 512 but not 513 which differ only in AL.

Comment: **Production code (not code golf) should use `jnc retry`**.  If you don't, it will work correctly on *some* systems, but there are systems (other than IvB) where you can in practice get `0` and `CF=0`.  On the original IvB, *you will not be able to underflow the buffer*, according to the Intel engineer who designed it and wrote the SO answer you linked: [What are the exhaustion characteristics of RDRAND on Ivy Bridge?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14443763)

Comment: Also note the `rdrand` and `rdseed` aren't specific to Intel; AMD has their own hardware implementation and enables those feature bits in CPUID.  IDK about other vendors like Via and Zhaoxin, but again for codegolf that doesn't matter.  There have been systems with broken `rdrand`, like some AMD Zen 2 (IIRC) microcode versions where it always returned 0, so not a good practice for production code to use it directly without careful checking and being ready to update your software for issues that crop up.  Normally we leave that to the kernel with system calls like `getentropy`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments section, here's my attempt at converting [Lemire's Method](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html) to Nasm. It outputs a random 32-bit number from [0,N].

Basically, took Peter's [C godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/ee3fKTqY5) and ported it to a [Nasm example](https://tio.run/##rVPbbtNAEH33V8wLkCAnyqWqSgyVolKhSBQeeACpiqK1vSSL1rvR7ri4oEp8BF/Ij4TZi5248ITwiz1nzpmZPbNm1vIql/cjxWx1OGTwvsZ9jcDAMFXqClRd5dzAZ0Pft5P03TrJkgxe81wwy0tYKeRbyt/UEsVeioKh0Ap@/fgJb3klDH9m4YbjTpdeVwuF89kGIde1Knm5cV0GRm03@BTolR4ZlNnyIXwnlXs6HOEVDEYx@yTQskgqdcfvaRrSUPXBMHuUPT@jbEXZNhg0Q3h@jEKb7G81ZVS5YFB1nAf4uhOSw0DCS8AONhxro6jV5SXMZw59SJLE8sLbNc6tTQLN5jCdeIkHyP6NRbM44SJvMNlKnTMJlGMGkyS8ieU0GbzhihuG/I811gqFBIEgLAgFuOPBQLdauJi@mK1jhdG/P75Cpe/8IXgpQmGPClW0aLQzazvPh30da1JH82CjTZR5sAnO8G3L9HEpuo7JmOw294tgaeksOPK@xBkCJ4xV1dJTXVMTmxbV/nSSKM7hsdjuwnBePJ@1K1jSTd2Ry3tNdySF6@UnKLRCJpT1ttcq/kG9Bf0H92OJK63uuMF28TSEhuWHq9Wqs9lYWk28Xx3ICzrFdJKMpdb7Red@z3nnNPH8NytLKGUKZxchxQtXtyt3S8E6JYZHkFuMfnbL@Aa@VZz6oxF0a0@88IM6xfQYuit1Gjb9Y9g6D2A7iL23BZMytrhuBPZLn0@6c/ra7Q1odYfDbw)

```
; Output a random number from [0,N]
;
; Debiased Integer Multiplication — Lemire's Method
;
; uint32_t bounded_rand(rng_t& rng, uint32_t range) {
;     uint32_t t = (-range) % range;
;     do {
;         uint32_t x = rng();
;         uint64_t m = uint64_t(x) * uint64_t(range);
;         uint32_t l = uint32_t(m);
;     } while (l < t);
;     return m >> 32;
; }


section .bss
    resb 10     
    num_str:

section .text
global _start

_start:

    ; Generate a random number until it is in the range [0, 8192]
    ; -----------------------------------------------------------
    mov     edi, 8192
    inc     edi       ; [0, 8193)
    mov     eax, edi
    xor     edx, edx
    neg     eax
    div     edi
.retry:
    rdrand  eax
    jnc     .retry
    imul    rax, rdi
    cmp     eax, edx
    jb      .retry
    shr     rax, 32

    ; At this point, EAX contains the unbiased random number
    ; -----------------------------------------------------------

    ; Convert number into ASCII
    mov rsi, num_str
    mov ecx, 10
.loop:
    xor edx, edx
    div ecx
    add dl, 48
    dec rsi
    mov [rsi], dl
    test eax, eax
    jnz .loop
    ; Write number
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rdx, num_str
    sub rdx, rsi
    syscall
    ; Exit
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

Let me know if there are any glaring mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: `mov     eax, edx        ; Move higher 32 bits of result to EAX` - That would make sense if you'd used `mul edi` and avoided most of those `mov` instructions, `imul rax, rdx` is a 64-bit non-widening multiply so the upper 32 bits are the top half of RAX, not writing RDX at all.  Your `shr rax, 32` at the end works makes sense for that.  `mul edi` is a 3-uop instruction on Intel, but you're saving enough `mov` and shift instructions that it's probably worth it for performance.  (I'm assuming this answer isn't intended to be code-golf at all.)

Comment: `mov rdi, num_str` / `add rdi, 10` is the most inefficient way possible to write `lea rdi, [rel num_str + 10]`.   [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) .  You could put a label at the end of the buffer, or use the `.size equ $ - num_str` trick.   Also, you're making a `write` system call so you don't need or want a terminating `0` byte.  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) for a version that uses stack space.

Comment: Oh, you started from unoptimized compiler output.  https://godbolt.org/z/ee3fKTqY5 is optimized compiler output (in a function where the range isn't constant, so it doesn't optimize away.  For a fixed constant, inlining `rand_range(8192)`, this compiles to just `rdrand eax` / `shr eax, 19`, which produces numbers from 0..8191.  For `rand_range(8193)`, the compile-time constant allows clang to optimize to just rdrand/shift/add/test in the retry loop.  (GCC does a weird store/reload for `_rdrand_step` loops, so I was looking at asm that doesn't retry.  Add a `jc retry` to the asm.)

Comment: That Godbolt link includes a `-m32` version to force compilers to use `mul r32` to get the high half in a separate register.  But it barely saves instructions; you only need the high half *after* the loop.  The loop condition is checking `(uint32_t)m` which is just EAX after either flavour of multiply, the low 32 of the product.

Comment: Updated the code to a more optimized Lemire version.

Comment: What is `mov     edi, edi` supposed to be doing?  EDI is already zero-extended to RDI from `inc     edi`, so it's not changing the value or FLAGS.  GCC's asm contains that instruction because it's a function arg that doesn't know is already zero-extended.  In hand-written asm, you can just take that arg as a 32-bit value that's required to already be zero-extended.

Comment: I'll change that, plus  `mov     eax, eax` is not needed because the high order bits are zeroed from `rdrand eax`, right? The optimized example uses it. https://godbolt.org/z/ee3fKTqY5

Comment: Right, `mov eax, eax` is useless.  Writing a 32-bit register *always* zero-extends to the full register.  Look at clang's asm which doesn't do that; it's just a GCC missed optimization probably because of the way they internally define the intrinsic.