# Faster than rand()?

Tags: c, random

I'm working on an algorithm which needs to generate millions of numbers as fast as possible. Actually I found out that the rand() function of my algorithm takes 75% of the process time.

So I'm looking for something faster. And I don't need a big range at all. (I only need integer numbers below 1000)

Do you know something I could use ?

Thanks !

Edit :

I use this numbers for shuffling groups of less than 1000 entities.

I found out more about the "fast rand". And there is SSE version version which is even faster and generates 4 numbers at a time.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-random-number-generator-on-the-intel-pentiumr-4-processor/

Comment: 75% of 3 seconds isn't much. Usually, `rand()` is very fast. How long does your code take to run to create 1 million numbers?

Comment: Don't think of 75% as "slow". After all, even if it runs in a nanosecond, *something* will take 100% of the time. If the program mainly does nothing except generate random numbers, you would expect that to take up most of the time. However, if you want it to be faster, that does tell you where to look.

Comment: I wasn't saying that it was "slow" but that's probably where I should start if I want to improve my algorithm.

Comment: What do you need the random variables for?  Random variables for something like Monte Carlo Integration, may not be suitable for encryption.

Comment: I always have to ask - did you get this from `gprof`? If so, don't believe it, because `gprof` ignores blocked time like I/O, as well as any time taken in non-pg-compiled libraries. If you are writing these numbers somewhere, that could well be the *real* time-taker. [*I use this method.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)

Comment: First show us some real numbers, how much it takes in seconds to generate how many numbers, and then also tell us what you do with them. Do you store them in a file? Do they just enter in some computation?

Comment: 1000 entities of what size? 1000 is a small number for a modern platform. I don't see that you have a real problem.

Comment: How "random" do your "random" numbers need to be? If you're on a Linux/glibc based system, your problem is that `rand` is actually implemented in terms of `random`, which is a rather high-quality (and therefore slow) PRNG. Lower-quality ones like a pure LCG should be much faster, but might have sufficiently bad statistical properties to make them unsuitable for your application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
static unsigned int g_seed;

// Used to seed the generator.           
inline void fast_srand(int seed) {
    g_seed = seed;
}

// Compute a pseudorandom integer.
// Output value in range [0, 32767]
inline int fast_rand(void) {
    g_seed = (214013*g_seed+2531011);
    return (g_seed>>16)&0x7FFF;
}
```

Comment: And where do you get it from that this is faster than the `rand()` implementation that Kevin's machine has?

Comment: I just tested it : takes 1.2s for 100 millions numbers, rand() takes 5s.
I'll have to check if it's truly random but thanks !

Comment: It is a bit more faster than rand(). There are some corner cases but not so big deal. @JensGustedt  and my pleasure kevinP

Comment: It resulted in a 35% decrease of time on my algorithm with similar results.
I guess I'll combine your fastrand with @Aaron Digulla answer to improve it a little more.

Comment: @KevinP: This is a simple [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) using the same parameters as the Microsoft `rand()` implementation. It's fast but not high-quality randomness.

Comment: weird, compiling with Visual studio 17, 10e7 invocations of `rand()` complete in 0.268 seconds,  but `fast_rand()` in 0.51 seconds.  Also tested Mersenne Twister with a uniform distribution,  it takes 0.9 seconds. So seems like `rand()` is the fastest

Answer (score 3):

[Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm is a quite fast yet balanced pseudo-random number generator.

Here is a sample implementation : http://fmg-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/mtwist.html

Comment: In most systems, `rand()` is a pseudo-random number generator. I'm wondering how slow his implementation actually is.

Comment: I guess they're not changing the default implementation because it would break pre-seeded softwares...

Comment: modern mersenne Twisters are really not that fast compared to their equally ranking alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Intel Ivy Bridge processor, you could very well offload random number generation to hardware using [RDRAND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) instruction.

This [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484164/what-is-the-latency-and-throughput-of-the-rdrand-instruction-on-ivy-bridge) talks about the throughput of RDRAND.

You could also identify if the processor supports RDRAND and use hardware offload or else fall back to software implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In most systems, rand() is a pseudo-random number generator. So the code should be just a few shift + bit-OR operations and able to produce millions of numbers per second on a typical PC. You don't say what you get and what your hardware is or which C library you're using, so it's hard to see why your implementation is "slow".

Maybe you can try to reuse bits: Take the lowest ten bits (= 1024 values), modulo 1000 to get the number range you want. Then shift and when you run out of bits, call `rand()` again for more bits.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is necessarily a good idea, re-using bits may not guarantee the period of the most likely linear congruent method he is using.

Comment: Modulo operations are not a good idea if you're looking for high performance.