# Is there a more efficient way to choose randomly in c other than using rand() srand()?

Tags: c, random

recently i started learning C , ive been working in some simple projects calculator,calendar,tempreture converter,rock paper scissors... Now im trying to build my own password generator,this program is based on random picking (numbers,letters,symbols...) to make a strong password.
so i looked for a function that picks randomly , and i found rand() and srand() with time(0)

i was dissapointed after i learnd how these functions work that it wasnt as good as random.randint() in python , and that the function would return the same value over and over if you execute in the same second (as u can see from the exemple IMAGE) is there any other function or algorithme i could use to solve this problem ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6xSS.png)

Comment: Slight mistake - you only call `rand()`once and print that value 4 times. Move that call to inside the for statement.

Comment: Sounds like you really mean _effective_ rather than _efficient_. What you're doing is very efficient but not very effective :)

Comment: You would have the same problem in Python if you called `random.randint()` outside the loop. The problem is your logic, not the language.

Comment: You've misunderstood a key piece of information. Calling `srand((unsigned) time(NULL))` several times in a single second will *seed* the pRNG with the same value, thus produce the same deterministic sequence. Calling `rand()` multiple times in a second is not an issue. See: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/2505965)

Comment: In any case, please do not post your code as an image. It is already text - simply copy and paste it into your question as text. Use the `{ }` button in the [edit]or to format it, creating a proper [mre].

Comment: @BoP Trueee thanks for helping me out much appreciated :D

Comment: There are plenty of pseudo random generators out there and while they are hard to invent, most of them are not hard to _implement_.  If speed is not an issue, you can select the one with the best "randomness" according to tests. If speed _is_ an issue, you can select a really fast one that may not have such good statistical properties. A good thing about not using `rand()` but a PRNG with known properties is that your program will then have exactly the same randomness on all platforms which makes testing your program easier.

Comment: @Barmar you r absolutely right excuse my poor logic .

Comment: @oka Thank u , it looks like i didn't understand how srand() and rand() exactly work , i'll use the { } button next time this is my first time posting a question here haha.

Comment: [Jokes](https://xkcd.com/221/) apart, there are alternatives. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237419/faster-than-rand

Comment: I think you need soemthing better than `rand()` to make a strong password.

Comment: tool/library recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can read `/dev/random` pseudofile to get random number (If your hardware has hardware random generator it will be a very good source of it)

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *rndfile = fopen("/dev/random", "r");
    int rnd;

    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        fread(&rnd, 1, sizeof(rnd), rndfile);
        printf("%d\n", rnd);
    }
    fclose(rndfile);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ezj4x6Eav

Comment: Be careful using `fread()` to read from `/dev/random` - the buffering could cause a read that fills the entire buffer, which is probably something like 8 KB.  Each time the file is opened and closed whatever is in that buffer is lost.  That could be very slow and/or deplete the system's entropy to the point that things like SSL connections fail.  Especially if the code here is called often.  To see what happens when a Linux system lacks entropy, build a RHEL system without `rng-tools`.

Comment: Also `getrandom()`