# How can I transform a random integer to a uniform real [0,1[ distribution

Tags: c++, random, distribution

On Wikipedia, I found the following [random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift):

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* The state must be seeded so that it is not everywhere zero. */

uint64_t s[ 2 ];

uint64_t next(void) { 
    uint64_t s1 = s[ 0 ];
    const uint64_t s0 = s[ 1 ];
    s[ 0 ] = s0;
    s1 ^= s1 << 23;
    return ( s[ 1 ] = ( s1 ^ s0 ^ ( s1 >> 17 ) ^ ( s0 >> 26 ) ) ) + s0;
}
```

Now, when implemented, (using a random seed for s[0] and s[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift)), this works nicely, but outputs numbers like:

```
2318509732609079156, 5455176535758408500, 14446583927462861784, 3420274542024626201, etc.
```

My question now is: How can I transform these numbers to a uniform real distribution [0,1[, i.e. with 0 included and 1 excluded?

Comment: Just divide the integer random number by 2.0^64

Comment: there's a whole library for that in C++11: [<random>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Do you have a reason for doing that yourself?

Comment: I'd recommend this talk about random generators in C++11: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-harmful ; getting random numbers right is hard.

Comment: Yes @DmitryLedentsov, speed.
I selected this algorithm in particular because it is known to be one of the fastest random number engines around. I am writing a program where the main speed bottleneck is random number generation, so as fast as the Mersenne Twister or Lagged Fibonnaci generators are, they are still slower than this one.

Comment: @PeterG.
Thank you very much, that seems to have done the trick! (At least, at first glance). But may I ask: How did you know that this was the number to divide by?

Comment: @MarkAnderson The maximum 64bit unsigned value is 2^64, so that's the maximum possible value of your generator. Assuming that `next` can return that value, dividing by this value can never be larger than 1.

Comment: @MarkAnderson thanks for the answer. It seems like a valid reason, however, it all then depends on the other properties that you expect of that generator, and at least [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046714/what-is-a-good-random-number-generator-for-a-game) has an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want a `double` result, simply cast the result of your random generator to `double` and divide by the maximum value (i.e. 2^64):

```
double result = next() / (double) std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
```

Note that some precision might be lost when converting to 64bit real values, so the values might not be exactly uniformly distributed. If this matters for your application, you shouldn't use this code...

edit: Sorry, this could also result in the value `1`. A simple workaround would be to repeat this until the value is not `1`, or making sure that `next()` never returns `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`.

edit: Even simpler, as inspired by 40two's answer: Call std::uniform_real_distribution with your random generator:

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
double random_number_in_01 = distribution(next);
```

Comment: Your original answer is misleading. If you divide by 2^64-1 in double precision you get non-uniformly distributed numbers since floating point numbers do not have uniform density in all intervals. For more information: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31657/uniformly-distributed-secure-floating-point-numbers-in-0-1

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 there's a way to produce uniformly distributed numbers over an interval with `std::uniform_real_distribution`:

```
// uniform_real_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
  double random_number_in_01 = distribution(generator);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I am quite aware of the standard library's random number generators, but in my case, speed is paramount. The generators in the standard library are fast, but I compared them to this simple algorithm, and they are significantly slower.

Comment: With regards to the C++11 random numbers model, your algorithm is a `random_engine`. Maybe you should try to blend into the C++11 random numbers by converting your algorithm to a custom `random_engine`, that you can then use with `std::uniform_real_distribution`.