# Create a Random 4 digit number for each record in Access or SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, random

I'm working in Access and I need to create a random 4 digit-number for a list of users separated into records. My query keeps returning the same random number for each record.

```
SELECT 1000 + (1999-1000)*RND() as [PassCodes], 
    stafflistEMAIL.Name, stafflistEMAIL.Description 
FROM stafflistEMAIL;
```

How can I make this work, the other answered I've viewed don't provide a solution?

Comment: It sounds like you are generating PIN numbers.  Is it very important to have unique numbers?  Might help us to know.

Comment: A random number is not unique, you know that, yes?

Comment: For queries, you can run the rand with a field: `Int(1000+(1999-1000)*Rnd([akey]))`

Answer (score 2):

Just as a thought, the following will give 4 random characters:

```
Mid(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetTempName,4,4)
```

For example:

```
906F
0818
25A5
F200
918F
A166
```

Answer (score 1):

[Repeating random variables in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2884972/122139)

Before calling `Rnd`, use the `Randomize` statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer.

Depending a lot on your goal, you can do something fun like this:

```
Right(Cstr(CInt(Len(stafflistEMAIL.Name)*Len(stafflistEMAIL.Description)/1000)),4)
```

Comment: If the system timer is on 1-second resolution, and queries come faster than this, this won't work.  You need to make sure the timer is ticking faster than queries are received.

Comment: If you are running your query apart from VBA, I'm not sure how to do what you want.  I would suggest you move it to VBA for good control -- presumably this is a fairly critical function.  I'm thinking, for example, that you want these numbers to be unique; so you need a way to check that, and VBA offers the control you need.

Comment: djconnel -- that is a great point.  Again, this argues for VBA; increment number +1 if timer is unchanged (of course that isn't random, but I assume it meets the need).