# Repeating random numbers in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, random

I have a Monte Carlo simulation in VBA. The client wants (dont question why) to fix random number sequence, i.e. every time you run the model, sequence shall stay the same. I managed to fix random seed as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884972/repeating-random-variables-in-vba). BUT it is not the same on different PCs. Any idea why and how can I also fix it on different machines?

Comment: Why not just create a sequence of random numbers and save the sequence for use in your application?

Comment: And this is perfectly logical - the clients want the Monte Carlo simulation to be repeatable.

Comment: Or you could, using **VBA** , code your own pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: @whytheq: I find that too gimmicky, and not too efficient

Comment: @Gary'sStudent If have an example of code in VBA for random number generation I would be very thankful to u

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeating random variables in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884972/repeating-random-variables-in-vba)

Comment: yeah considering how it turned out, you are probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rnd` function with a negative argument to achieve a repeating list of random numbers.

Here is a link to the documentation:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/rnd-function-HA001228901.aspx

`Note    To repeat sequences of random numbers, call Rnd with a negative argument immediately before using Randomize with a numeric argument. Using Randomize with the same value for number does not repeat the previous sequence.`

---

```
Sub TestRandomNumberSequence()

rnd (-10)

    For i = 1 To 5

        Randomize 10
        MsgBox BetweenRange(1, 20, rnd)

    Next i

    'always returns the following sequence

    '5
    '18
    '19
    '6
    '17

End Sub

Function BetweenRange(min As Integer, max As Integer, ByVal rnd As Double) As Integer

BetweenRange = Int((max - min + 1) * rnd + min)

End Function
```

Comment: Hmm, true, but strange, that I get different number on different computers, must be error in my code. Thx

Comment: This is the same answer already included in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884972/repeating-random-variables-in-vba

Answer (score 1):

As per your request, please checkout the following link:

[Wabash College Download](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://www3.wabash.edu/econometrics/econometricsbook/chapters/Ch09MonteCarloSimulation/ExcelFiles/RNGTheory.xls&ei=h4lCU9-1Dc3gsATT2IKYCQ&usg=AFQjCNEk_J5pSZTGYK7sOkBVsvdt9EhydQ&sig2=GeCgLZqwGomoqgdQSkt2BQ&bvm=bv.64125504,d.cWc)

Comment: Thx for that too, but it uses RND method from VBA too I think