# How to set a seed for the generating random numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, random

I am running a experiment in excel using NORM.S.INV(RAND())

Is there a way to set the seed for the random function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting seed for excel random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161114/setting-seed-for-excel-random-number)