# how to draw a pair of boy and a girl in a competition excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, random

I have 20 kids composing of 10 boys in column A and 10 girls in Column B . I need excel vba to choose a pair of boy and girl at random  for the 20 kids.

thanks

Comment: Could you sort both alphabetically then adapt =Rand() formula to randomise selection?

Comment: why would you need VBA?

Comment: Take your pick of off the shelf  (code and formula) solutions google gives immediately:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/vba-code-for-generate-random-number-between-2/f662cdd8-a101-46a4-aeb8-fde4942f8985

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeating random variables in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884972/repeating-random-variables-in-vba)    Just set two ranges (1 for boy, 1 for girl)

Answer (score 2):

This is overkill, but I slapped it together just together just for fun.  It selects a random name from any number of lists (one per column) including colors and sound while choosing.

<sup>I just hit double-backspace while about to submit my edit, losing it all, so this is the short version -  less information and links.</sup>

[image: img]

```
Option Explicit  'always use this!

Const shtName = "RandVBA" 'name of worksheet
Const cellRange = "B5:C14" 'cell range (each column gets separate selection)

Public Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" _
   (ByVal dwFreq As Long, _
    ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long


Sub chooseRandomColumns()
    'selects a random cells from each column in range, with colors and sound

    Randomize
    Dim cr As Range, col As Range, x As Long, n As Long, winners As String
    Set cr = Sheets(shtName).Range(cellRange)

    For x = 1 To 20
        cr.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'reset background colors
        winners = "" 'erase winners names
        For Each col In cr.Columns
            n = Int(Rnd() * cr.Rows.Count) + cr.Row 'pick random cell in column
            Sheets(shtName).Cells(n, col.Column).Interior.Color = _
                RGB(Int(Rnd() * 256), Int(Rnd() * 256), Int(Rnd() * 256)) 'random color
            winners = winners & " - " & Sheets(shtName).Cells(n, col.Column) & vbLf
        Next col

        Beep Int(Rnd() * 2000) + 300, 125 'random beep 125ms/300-2300Hz
        DoEvents 'catch-up
    Next x

    MsgBox "The winners are:" & vbLf & vbLf & winners, vbExclamation, "Winners!"

End Sub
```

**Download** sample `.XLSM` workbook with these examples [here](https://storage.jumpshare.com/download/ri6poZ8xQE2lhY4llyWarhYu52OqzcFtOFRz53srU7A73SMV6qGraZr3qvKebZwepwn8eVHqDjeIQHzkFPoNfQ).  (File contains VBA/Macros so you may get a security warning when opening.)

---

## Pick randomly from a list Without Excel

**You can also do this online (completely without Excel) using [RANDOM.ORG](https://www.random.org/lists/).**

[image: img]

---

## Pick randomly from a list with Excel (No VBA)

[image: img]

**Formula in `C3`:**

```
=OFFSET(C5,RAND()*10,0)
```

**Formula in `D3`:**

```
=OFFSET(D5,RAND()*10,0)
```

---

### More Information:

- **[Offset Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) (Excel)**
- **[Rand Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rand-function-4cbfa695-8869-4788-8d90-021ea9f5be73) (Excel)**

Comment: Had to +1 this as it's a completely over the top answer to a question that'll probably be closed. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without VBA as well -

see the formula in screenshot -

[image]