# The Rnd function in the Workbook_open event still returns the same value

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that uses the Rnd function. This function randomizes a total of 1-10.

```
Public Sub Welcome()  
    Dim WelcomeStart As String  
    wsAssistant.Range("D2") = 1 + Round(Rnd * 9, 0)  
    WelcomeStart = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wsAssistant.Range("D2"),wsAssistant.Range("B2:C11"), 2, 0)  
    wsAssistant.Range("E2") = WelcomeStart  
End Sub
```

Cells B2:B11 contain numbers from 1 to 11.
However, there are texts in cells C2:C11.

The number drawn is the value sought for the vlookup function, which contains the return.
The startup procedure with the module works correctly. Return random numbers and welcome phrases.

However, when I place this procedure in the Workbook_open event, the Rnd function returns 7 for each value.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()  
    Application.DisplayFullScreen = True  
    UserForm1.Show  
    Welcome 
    wsAssistant.Range("E2").Speak  
End Sub
```

The idea is that when the file is opened, a random greeting phrase will be read. In the current situation, when the return from item 7 is constantly returned, this solution no longer makes sense.
I also added a line of code that clears cell D2 so that when the file is opened, the cell will be blank, but that doesn't help either.

Please tell me whether it is possible for the Rnd function to return random values when opening a file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating random variables in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884972/repeating-random-variables-in-vba)

Comment: To randomize 1 to 10, in VBA, I suggest `Int(Rnd * 10 + 1)`

Comment: Int(Rnd *10+1) also returns the same value.  The original solution returned 7, but now it returns 8. But it's still not a random value.

Comment: Grzegorz, as `Randomize` solved your problem, it is a good practice here at SO to mark the answer as an Answer. this way your question will appear as full green among the other questions.  Other people with similar questions will look at yours and choose to see yours instead of others non-asnwered (non-green) and, besides helping more people, you may get the benefit of more UpVotes.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code you should understand first that:

> Rnd generates a **pseudo-random number**: For any given initial seed, the same number sequence is generated because each successive call to the Rnd function uses the previous number as a seed for the next number in the sequence.

Your seed in `Round(Rnd * 9, 0)` is the same ever.
To fix your code you have to seed it with some initial **random** value: usually we use `Randomize` in the line before to seed it with the current system clock.
So:

```
Public Sub Welcome()  
    Dim WelcomeStart As String  
    
    Randomize '<= just this
    wsAssistant.Range("D2") = 1 + Round(Rnd * 9, 0)  
    WelcomeStart = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wsAssistant.Range("D2"),wsAssistant.Range("B2:C11"), 2, 0)  
    wsAssistant.Range("E2") = WelcomeStart  
End Sub
```

Edit:
Of course, for security critical apps and IOT, it is not a good idea to seed with current time, because it is predictable.

Comment: Randomize solved my problem. Thank you very much for your help.