# same random number should not generate again and again?

Tags: objective-c, random

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C++ random number generator without repeating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111214/c-random-number-generator-without-repeating-numbers)
>   [Unique random numbers in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1)

I am doing as following

```
int y = arc4random() % 50;
```

I am using objective-c
Now as I don't want same number again and again, like if 6 is once I get, then I don't need 6 again, because I am calling this line again and again and taking random numbers.

Comment: What language are you using? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299401/which-of-these-algorithm-is-better-in-performance-and-order-for-generating-n-uniq/4299411#4299411 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858610/different-numbers-from-1-to-10/1858800#1858800 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111214/c-random-number-generator-without-repeating-numbers/4111248#4111248 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

How about you generate an array (1,2,3,4,5,6,...) and sort it randomly, then read the array elements one at a time.

Otherwise, if you use a random number generator and make sure it only gives you numbers you haven't seen before, you can only call it a limited number of times.

*sorting randomly* will depend on what language you're using.

Comment: how about to add number to array and check in array if exists then don't run ?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Have you seen the other questions mentioned above?