# random number generation and exclusion of the generated numbers

Tags: java

Is it possible to do this in Java ? I want to generate a random number such that given a range say for example: between 1 and 70 - everytime the random number is generated it should be excluded from generation results.
so [1,70] rand = 56 (now 56 shouldn't be considered next time)
[1,70] = 63 (now 56,63 should be excluded from generation till my code runs)

Comment: Duplicate to question : **[Java Creating Random Numbers with No Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/java-creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates)**

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to shuffling an array of numbers containing [1..70] and then dealing them out one at a time.  Look up "shuffle algorithm" on Google.  Here's a link http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html

Comment: Or better use the shuffle algorithm that comes with JDK. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Comment: Yes, I forgot that was in there.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question here: [How can I generate a random number within a range but exclude some?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520835/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-within-a-range-but-exclude-some)

The general strategy is something like filling an array with 70 values.  Just remove the values that you randomly generate as per the link above.

Answer (score 1):

you could populate the range into an array and shuffle the array. This would be inefficient though for very large ranges

Answer (score 1):

Another trivial alternative, using HashMaps to keep track of random numbers.
It is sort of quick and dirty.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hmRandomNum = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

Integer a = < generate random number>

if( hmRandomNum.get(a) == null)
{
     hmRandomNum.put(a,a);
}
else
{
     // ignore this random number. this was already selected and present in the hashmap.
}

//Iterate depending on how many numbers you want.
```