# Making a Pin Number Pad Randomizer

Tags: random, vb6

All I want to do is to "scatter" the numbers from 0 to 9 inside a NumPad like the Pin Number Pads I saw on the internet.
So far, this is my code:

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
   For i = 0 To 9
       Command1(i).Caption = Int(10 * Rnd)
   Next i
End Sub
```

wherein Command1(i) is the name of each number buttons I have. Each of them has an index equal to their caption, for now. (Well, there isn't really a dependence between the caption and the index, so let's just leave it at that)

Now, as I said, I want to scatter the numbers or rearrange the numbers, and that's why I have that code.

Do you have a better suggestion on this? :/ I just can't get it. I scanned Google for "No Duplication Random numbers" thingy but I just can't get it.

Oh, in case you'll worry about the whole pin number pad program wherein you don't see any labels or text boxes or whatever, just ignore it. I just want what I'm aiming for now.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Oh, thanks for that Wikipedia Topic, Plutonix... finally got it!Private Sub Command3()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim tmp As Integer

    Randomize
    For i = 0 To 9 - 1
        ' Pick a random entry.
        j = Int((9 - i + 1) * Rnd + i)

        ' Swap the numbers.
        tmp = Command1(i).Caption
        Command1(i).Caption = Command1(j).Caption
        Command1(j).Caption = tmp
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click(Index As Integer)
    Text1.Text = Text1.Text & Command1(Index).Caption
    Call Command3
End Sub

Comment: there are numerous Shuffle code samples here in various languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different numbers from 1 to 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858610/different-numbers-from-1-to-10)