# PHP Shuffle in PHP 7.1+ produces different results

Tags: php, random, shuffle

I use the shuffle() function to emulate a letter bag in a word game.

I recently upgraded from PHP 5 to PHP 7, and have found that on the newer version, the shuffle function isn't quite as good for my purposes.

I used to start with the letters clumped and it would shuffle them nicely so there was a decent but unpredictable letter order. On 7.1+, it frequently produces clumps of the same letters, whereas getting those clumps was rare on 5.x

I saw that they changed the internal algorithm in 7.1.

Is there any way to emulate the older way shuffle worked in order to produce results more closely to how they were in PHP 5?

Comment: In what way is it "not quite as good"? This is probably important for recommending an alternative.

Comment: I am shuffling letters, to emulate a letter bag in a word game. but the results I get on 7.1+ produces clumps of the same letters, whereas getting those clumps was rare on 5.x . I use to start with the letters clumped and it would shuffle them nicely so there was a decent but unpredictable letter order, now it ends up with groups of the same letter. I have tried splitting them up before shuffling, but the results are still not right.

Comment: One thing to be careful of is that human brains are very bad at creating or judging randomness. Have you compared the results of each version to what happens if you actually pick letters out of a bag?

Comment: Clumps where there weren't previously may indicate *better* randomness. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910215/need-for-predictable-random-generator; my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/910280/1902010 there has a useful graphic. There's also guidance in that thread on building a less-random approach that avoids clumps.

Comment: Implementing your own shuffle function is not so hard, and you can customize the randomness depending on your need

Comment: @IMSoP , yes I have taken into account how it would be in a game situation, but even taking that into account, when someone picks up 4 of the same letter , it is a highly unlikely outcome , but its happening a lot, whereas on the old shuffle , this was not the case. IT may happen, sure , but not as a common thing.

Comment: @CharlieSmith That's just it, though, picking up four of the same letter *is* fairly likely. Read up on "the birthday paradox", and try some actual experiments; I bet you'll find that PHP 7 is giving you a more *realistic* letter bag. Now, you might decide that a less random one is more *fun*, but then you'll have to decide exactly what biases you want to introduce.

Answer (score 2):

### What is Randomness?

One thing that computers have in common with the human brain is that they're very bad at being random.

You can't actually write down a set of steps that creates randomness, without some external input (throwing a dice, measuring radioactive decay, listening to an untuned radio, [staring at lava lamps](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/ssl/lava-lamp-encryption/)). All you can try to do is make an actually predictable sequence that *looks* random. Unfortunately, it's easy to fool the human brain into thinking something's random, or into spotting patterns where there are none, so you have to be really careful in how you design this "pseudo-randomness".

A relevant example of how the human brain perceives randomness is the fact that with only 23 people in a room, there's a 50% chance that two of them will have the same birthday. This is so surprising that it's often referred to as the "[birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)", even though it's mathematically quite straight-forward. The clumps of letters in your word game are very similar.

### What Changed?

For a long time, PHP had two different "pseudo-random number generators":

- A system-dependent algorithm, exposed to users as `rand()`, which had a bunch of problems.
- Something called the "Mersenne Twister", exposed to users as `mt_rand()`, which was generally better in all respects.

In PHP 7.1, [a series of changes were made](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/rng_fixes) to basically eliminate the `rand()` version and use the Mersenne Twister algorithm everywhere. This included `shuffle`.

None of the rest of the algorithm changed: it was always *intended* to put the elements into a random order regardless of their starting positions, so your ability to affect it by clumping the starting positions was a bug, not a feature.

### How random was shuffle in the different versions?

I wrote a [quick script](https://gist.github.com/IMSoP/08676e4d7056932423fec47da2e5349b) to test if `shuffle` had any biases:

1. Generate an array with 100 items, 0 to 99
2. Shuffle it
3. Mark down the new position of each element
4. Repeat lots of times

The result is a 100 x 100 grid showing how often, for instance, element 0 ends up in position 42.

If the shuffling is truly random, we should expect that as we repeat the shuffle enough times, every element ends up in every position just as often. In other words, our grid should have the same count for every combination.

I ran the same code on PHP 7.0 (when `shuffle()` used the old `rand()` implementation) and 7.1 (when it used the `mt_rand()` implementation) and visualised the results (script also included [in the gist](https://gist.github.com/IMSoP/08676e4d7056932423fec47da2e5349b)). The columns of the image represent the 100 elements in the array, and the rows the different positions they could end up in. Blue pixels represent combinations that happened less often than expected, and red pixels combinations that happened more often than expected.

For PHP 7.1, the image looks mostly black, because the numbers were pretty close to perfectly equal across all combinations:

[image: Results for PHP 7.1]

For PHP 7.0, however, there are some very visible "hot" and "cold" areas!

[image: Results for PHP 7.0]

So in the old algorithm, there are certain swaps that were much less likely to happen. These biases presumably happened to fit with the order you placed the items in to make it less likely than it should have been for certain letters to occur at certain times in the game.

### What if you want to bias your shuffle?

The new algorithm should more accurately reflect what would happen in a real game - all the letters have an equal chance of appearing at any time in the game.

But maybe you find it more *fun* to "rig" the order, so that you don't get the same letter several times in a row, or you're likely to have a mix of consonants and vowels.

You could achieve that by re-implementing the shuffle algorithm, and then tweaking the probabilities of certain things happening.

The core of the algorithm is this (essentially what changed in 7.1 was the definition of `RAND_RANGE`):

```c
while (--n_left) {
    RAND_RANGE(rnd_idx, 0, n_left, PHP_RAND_MAX);
    if (rnd_idx != n_left) {
        temp = hash->arData[n_left];
        hash->arData[n_left] = hash->arData[rnd_idx];
        hash->arData[rnd_idx] = temp;
    }
}
```

This picks items at random one by one, as you'd expect (but from last to first, because it happens to be easier), but to save re-allocating the array each time you "remove" an item, it uses a neat trick: it *swaps* the current element of the array with a random element earlier in the array.

In PHP code, it would look something like this (untested!):

```php
$n_left = count($array);
while (--$n_left) {
    $rnd_idx = mt_rand(0, $n_left);
    // The if statement is just skipping the swap if our random choice is for it to stay where it is
    if ($rnd_idx != $n_left) {
        $temp = $array[$n_left];
        $array[$n_left] = $array[$rnd_idx];
        $array[$rnd_idx] = $temp;
    }
}
```

To add bias to this, you just need to change the way `$rnd_idx` is chosen. You could for instance say that if the chosen letter (`$array[$rnd_idx]`) is the same as the previously chosen one, pick again. You could have a whole function deciding how "good" a pick it is, and introducing bias that way.

Since "fun" is subjective, not mathematically definable, you'd have to just test a bunch of things and see which one you liked the results of.

Comment: Those graphics illustrate this in a way no amount of sample code could. Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [random_int](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.random-int.php) function, which is suitable for cryptographic use.
Then you could use an implementation of the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle algorithm:

```
function shuffle($array) {
    $random_array = array();
    $countArray = count($array) - 1;

    while (count($array) != 0) {
        $randomValue = random_int(0, $countArray);
        $random_array[] = $array[$randomValue];

        if(($randomValue + 1) == count($array)) {
            array_splice($array, $randomValue, ($randomValue - $countArray + 1));
        } else {
            array_splice($array, $randomValue, ($randomValue - $countArray));
        }

        $countArray--;
    }

    return $random_array;
}
```

Comment: As I've said in the comments, the new results are almost certainly *more* random, not less, so this is likely to give the same patterns that the question considers "bad".

Comment: See my answer for confirmation that the old algorithm was considerably less random than the new one. Note also that the shuffle algorithm in PHP is considerably more efficient than this, because it uses element swapping (a bit like a bubble sort) rather than repeated splices.